# VideoJS on Google Chrome and IE9

Tags: video.js

I'm trying to run my code in some browsers. It works fine in Firefox and Opera, but in IE9 and Chrome it only works fine the first time.
After, when I want to run this code or another again it shows me the next warning:

"Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:"http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=dropdowndeals&userId=RR8BRgZAQDCRcXxJEAgX1g&CTID=1049999"."

However, if I delete the cache of the browser and run the code again, the code run without problems, but only the first time of course.
This problem is only on Google Chrome and IE9.

Do you have any suggestion, please?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on a users machine. It looks like it's AdWare that tries to parse the script tag, but doesn't like it when the type isn't javascript. If you use AdBlock or similar for the browser it should work, but this is just covering up the problem.

The end game would probably be to remove the adware completely.